# Plone send e-mail twice when deleting an item (Content rules)

Tags: email, plone, rules

I defined a Content Rule that send an e-mail when deleting an item in my Plone site.

The problem I had is when I choose "Actions/Delete" and Plone shows the floating window asking for a confirmation, the e-mail is already beign sent, even before I confirm, so I receive two e-mails: One when I select "delete" and another one when I confirm it. If I decide not to delete, the e-mail is sent.

Why is Plone sending an e-mail before I confirm the item remove?

- Plone 4.2.4 (4210)
- CMF 2.2.7
- Zope 2.13.19

Thanks

Comment: Flagged this quest being a dup of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218272/plone-reacting-to-object-removal, HTH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason may be that the delete action actually deletes things twice. The first time happens when you select the action and is used to trigger a check for related and linked items that refer to the item you are about to delete. This first 'delete' is then rolled back. The second delete happens after you actually click confirm.